# Symfony2 annotation routing causes cache:clear to fail

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I'm having a bunch of problems with routing in Symfony2 and I'm at my wits end searching for an answer.

I'm currently trying to use the `@Route` annotation. In the `dev` environment with debug enabled, everything works. In `prod` with debug enabled, everything works. If I disabled debug, only the index route responds, everything else returns a 404.

I initially thought it was the cache, so I followed the usual process of clearing it. That led to my next problem:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route" in method LeagueOfData\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction() does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

This error appears when you run `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` or `bin/console cache:clear --env=dev`.

So I checked everything was set up correctly (bare in mind, this works completely fine in the browser with debug enabled no matter the environment).

**routing.yml**

```
parser:
    resource: "@LeagueOfData/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

This is included in `config.yml` and `routing_dev.yml` (due to the dev override).

**AppKernal.php**

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new LeagueOfData\LeagueOfData()
    ];

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

`SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` is registered correctly. (Full source: https://github.com/Acaeris/lol-parser/blob/broken-routing/app/AppKernel.php)

**app.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**app_dev.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

As you can see, not much difference. The key seems to be in enabling debug... but why?

Full source is on GitHub if it'll help anyone: https://github.com/Acaeris/lol-parser/tree/broken-routing

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it with an `use` statement, as example:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
```

Hope this help

Comment: `@Route` already has a matching use statement in the controllers, otherwise it wouldn't work even with debug enabled.

Comment: How about using this : Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route?